# What data type should a time difference column in oracle sql be?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Hey so I have a database where i have a started and a completed timestamp. Now I need a third one for the time difference which I want to set by calculating completed - started in the setter of the variable in my java code so what data type should this column be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Oracle you want to use [intervals](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i38598) to represent a time difference so either an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` or `INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH` data type.

However, do you really need a third column? You can easily compute it from the other two columns as required (and could even create a virtual column rather than storing the calculated value). Then you would not have issues of updating either the start or end and forgetting to update the difference column and them becoming out of sync.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1bc74c/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table (
  start_time  TIMESTAMP,
  end_time    TIMESTAMP,
  difference  GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( end_time - start_time )
);

INSERT INTO your_table ( start_time, end_time )
SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP, SYSTIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '01:02:03' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1bc74c/1/0)**:

```
|              START_TIME |                END_TIME | DIFFERENCE |
|-------------------------|-------------------------|------------|
| 2017-11-23 10:12:06.741 | 2017-11-23 11:14:09.741 |  0 1:2:3.0 |
```

Answer (score -2):

It should be returning number, when you subtracting 2 different date that will return difference in no of days.

Thanks
Thangamani Eraniyan

Comment: "i have a started and a completed timestamp" - so the difference will be an interval not a number.

Comment: Subtracting 2 different date field will return  numbers      select sysdate - (sysdate-1/24) from dual 
returns 0.0416666 what is 1 hour.....

Comment: Yes, but subtracting two **timestamps** [will return an interval](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#g196492). So the equivalent query `select systimestamp - (systimestamp - interval '1' hour) from dual` will return `+00 01:00:00.000000`, which is an interval, not a number.

Comment: I agree,  but i am referring to 2 different date with time stamp,

Comment: I don't understand. Dates and timestamps are different data types in Oracle.  Dates always have times in Oracle of course, but that doesn't make them timestamps, and 'date with time stamp' doesn't make sense here as they are different things. The question says they are timestamps, not dates.